# Whats bigger? lim n->infinity n^x or lim n->infinity x^n

Tags: calculus, limits, computer-science

What is bigger?

lim n->infinity n^x

or

lim n->infinity x^n

I have a relationship where I am trying to find the lim n->infinity (2^n + n^20) / 3^n and am having a hard time deciphering it.

Comment: Technically, they are both infinity, and thus neither is bigger than the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the question asks is not what you probably mean, since 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^{n}=\infty\text{ for }x>1.
$$
What you probably care about is
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{x}}{x^{n}}=0\text{ for }x>1.
$$
In other words, $n^{x}$ is in $O(x^{n})$. See if you can prove this.

Answer (score 0):

That later, $x^n$, is faster. You should get 0 as the limit after splitting the fraction and distributing the limit

Comment: Upon evaluating the limit that way i ended up with 0 + 0 = 0, not 2/3. Could you show how why 2/3 is the expected limit?

Comment: You should get $ 0 $.  $ \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2^n}{3^n} = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n = 0$

Comment: Yes zero, that was a typo.